# data loss when sending across type NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, encoding, nsdata, decoding

I am currently in the middle of implementing the network layer of my game, i am making progress however i have come across something very odd which i was hoping someone could shed some might on:

Before sending my data across i am encoding it into type NSData (message.cards = [MovePlayer beginEncodeMyCards:myCards];) and then assigning it to a pointer (message.cards)

```
MessageMove message;
message.message.messageType = kMessageTypeMove;
/**/message.cards = [MovePlayer beginEncodeMyCards:myCards];/**/
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)];
```

If i do all the decoding on the client side as follows :

```
MessageMove *myMessage  = (MessageMove *) [data bytes];
/**/myCards = [MovePlayer beginDecodeMyCards:myMessage->cards cardArray:myCards];/**/
```

everything works fine, i am able to decode myMessage->cards, however when i try doing the same after sending the object remotely i can see the correct message type (kMessageTypeMove) but not the cards data (myMessage->cards).

if anyone can please shed some light to this i would greatly appreciate it

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tl;dr, use NSCoding to serialise your objects.**

You can't send pointers to a different process, because the pointers will all be wrong on the other side.

Lets say on the sending machine, you have this:

```
NSLog(@"cards: %p", message.cards);
//prints "cards: 0xDEADBEEF"
```

This says that the chunk of memory for the NSArray* object starts at the memory address 0xDEADBEEF. This is all correct at this point.

Now, you send that `0xDEADBEEF` pointer to another computer. The computer gets the pointer, **but the memory at `0xDEADBEEF` does not have an NSArray in it on the other computer**. There could be *anything* in that region of memory. You've sent a pointer, but you haven't actually sent any of the data with it.

Long story short, just use `NSCoder` for serialisation because it's very good.

Comment: thanks for the response, do you have an example i can follow?

Comment: It turns out i am doing the serializing you were referring to within beginEncode, this method returns a pointer to the NSData containing information of my cards. I am still not sure on how i can send the entire value over rather than just the pointer....

Comment: Basically, don't do this: `[NSData dataWithBytes:&message length:sizeof(message)]`. Do this: `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:message]`.